# Link Assemblys failed unexpectedly (Xamarin.ios.dll)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try to compile in release mode I get the error, while in Debug works great. I am trying to archive an APK but I can't due to Xamarin.ios.dll error

I tried deleting obj and bin folders and recompile them individually and it does work, but when I try to archive and an error appears asking me to check if I can compile the project.

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler/NSUrlSessionDataTaskStream/<ReadAsync>d__14::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: instruction at Mono.Cecil.Cil.InstructionOffset..ctor(Instruction instruction) at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadAsyncMethodBody(AsyncMethodBodyDebugInformation async_method) at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadCustomDebugInformations(MethodDefinition method) at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadDebugInfo() at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadMethodBody() at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadMethodBody(MethodDefinition method) at Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader.ReadMethodBody(MethodDefinition method) at Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition.<>c.<get_Body>b__41_0(MethodDefinition method, MetadataReader reader) at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TRet& variable, TItem item, Func`3 read)
at Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition.get_Body()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute() at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() MultiPlatFormXamarin.Android
```

Also, Xamarin.iOS is on the references of Xamarin.Android, is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand, you're trying to create ap APK (android), or an .IPA (iOS) ?

Comment: I am trying to build an APK

Comment: Since APK is for Android, you should definitely NOT have a reference to Xamarin.iOS in your project. Check your Android references, and to be sure, right click on your solution, go to Options, Configurations, Configuration Mappings, and uncheck your iOS project when building Android (i.e when building in "Any CPU")

Comment: After deleting Xamarin.iOS from Android references it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I'am adding my previous comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since APK is for Android, you should definitely NOT have a reference to Xamarin.iOS in your project. Check your Android references, and to be sure, right click on your solution, go to Options, Configurations, Configuration Mappings, and uncheck your iOS project when building Android (i.e when building in "Any CPU")